# How to load a loader on html until all images are loaded using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, networking, loader

I have simple angular js application. Here i am fetching images from google drive and showing in page.

Here i am trying to show a loader until the images are fully loaded in my page. Sometime when i have low bandwidth it's taking time to load images from google drive. So `i want to implement a loader on my screen until all images are fully loaded`.

> How can i know when images are fully loaded, then i can hide my
>   loader. i don't want to use setTimeout().

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body ng-app="basicApp">
        <div ng-controller="ListController">
<h1 ng-if="loading"> loading</h1>
         <div ng-if="!loading"  class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"  ng-repeat="url in urls" imageload>
              <div>
                  <div>
                      <div class="wsite-image wsite-image-border-none " style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;margin-left:0;margin-right:0;text-align:center">
                          <a>
                              <img src={{url}} alt={{url}} style="width:auto;max-width:100%"
                              />
                          </a>
                          <div style="display:block;font-size:90%"></div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**Controller**

```
    app.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$location', '$window', function ($scope, $location, $window) {

  var data = [
    'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1wZdBP8CMyLDOFGcvWY7KpffMhTRBHt1J',
    'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1zc1LqOPUQLbL4-LKBlDAOsetcqMgcWpi',
    'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1lB4SaiYedYfsxlXJEykC9ErJq8R40e3y'
  ]
    function getAll() {
         $scope.urls = data;

    }
    function init() {
      $scope.loading = true;
        getAll();
    }
    init();
}]);
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('imageload', ['$timeout', function ($timeout, $scope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, ele) {
            $timeout(function () {
                var img = angular.element(ele.find('img')[0]);
                console.log(img);
                $scope.loading = true;
                img.bind('load', function () {
                  console.log('img is loaded');
                    $scope.loading = false;

                });

            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

please check my [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/bOCFYKTTSaBicdSLZ3QK?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean variable and assign value according to the state,

```
 <h1 ng-if="loading"> loading</h1>
    <div ng-if="!loading" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" ng-repeat="url in urls">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="wsite-image wsite-image-border-none " style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;margin-left:0;margin-right:0;text-align:center">
            <a>
              <img src={{url}} alt={{url}} style="width:auto;max-width:100%" />
            </a>
            <div style="display:block;font-size:90%"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and in controller,

```
 function getAll() {
    $scope.urls = data;
    $scope.loading = false;
  }

  function init() {
    $scope.loading = true;
    getAll();
  }
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/bOCFYKTTSaBicdSLZ3QK?p=preview)**

Comment: tried but it is not showing till images are not fully loaded

Comment: It should work , are you loading the images via http call

Comment: can you propduce a plunker

Comment: i posted a plunkr in my question

Comment: that does not show anything related to loading, its just static data

Comment: code is there, i think you have faster bandwidth that's way you are getting my question i think.

Comment: can you tell me how to update a `$scope` inside a directive

Comment: you should pass it

Comment: `app.directive('imageload', ['$timeout', function ($timeout, $scope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, ele) {
            $timeout(function () {
                var img = angular.element(ele.find('img')[0]);
                console.log(img);
                $scope.loading = true;
                img.bind('load', function () {
                    $scope.loading = false;
                    console.log('img is loaded');
                });

            });
        }
    };
}]);`

Comment: can you check plunkr again, and also i have updated my question with your answer and new directive